# Print failed url request from HTTPError in Python

Tags: python, http, url, error-handling, urlrequest

I'm trying to catch when an error using `urlopen` occurs by giving both the error code and the url request that fails. I'm able to get the error code by doing:

```
    except urllib.request.HTTPError as e:
         print(e.code)
```

but I can't do the same thing by doing `e.req.full_url`, maybe I don't understand what the error means when it gives me this:

```
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
        urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Is there any way I can get the url request that caused the error in this manner?

Comment: Share the entire code.

Comment: The entire code is too long to post, I've included what I think is necessary just because I request url's multiple times.